# How do I allow attributes without escaping them?

Tags: php, html

I'm using TinyMCE and I allow users to submit HTML code. code. I'm inserting this code into a database so im using PHP's mysql_real_escape_string, but the thing is when I do that it escapes the quotes given by TinyMCE and the styling done is destroyed.

So my question is how do I allow it so users can submit HTML code with attributes while still preventing mysql injections.

here's my code

```
if($_POST)
{
    $landingPage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['landingPage']);
    $landingPage = strip_tags($landingPage, '<p><em><span><strong>');
}
```

Comment: You should switch the order of your commands. `mysql_real_escape_string` should be last.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You’re going to have to do a _lot_ of sanitization if you want to allow some HTML attributes, and you’re not going to be 100% safe.

Comment: I use HTML Purifier for my WYSIWIG intake: http://htmlpurifier.org/ It allows you to specify which elements to accept etc... have a read.